# Can't create table with boolean column using SQLAlchemy on Redshift

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

After a succesfull connection to Redshift, I'm trying to ensure my tables exist in the cluster. This is the code I'm running:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, SMALLINT, Column


Base = declarative_base()


class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a_table"

    id = Column(SMALLINT, primary_key=True)
    a_boolean_column = Column(Boolean)


# example values
engine = create_engine(
    URL.create(
        drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
        username="username",
        password="password",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=5439,
        database="dev",
    )
)

base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "a_boolean_column"
LINE 12:  a_boolean_column BOOLEAN, 
          ^

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE a_table (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        a_boolean_column BOOLEAN, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

]
```

I've tried using the `BOOLEAN` data type from `sqlalchemy`, and tried setting a default value, but both failed.

Versions:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.47
sqlalchemy-redshift==0.8.13
```

Comment: Well one thing to note is that you're not using the `sqlalchemy-redshift` plugin because it's defaulting back to `psycopg2`. It's been a few years since I tried to set up table migrations on Redshift and all I remember of the experience (going through `psycopg2`) was 3 days of hell before I gave up. I think the bindings are a bit more mature now

Comment: Try using https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-redshift/

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you are correct. I changed `drivername="postgresql+psycopg2"` to `drivername="redshift+psycopg2"` and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question if you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to force `sqlalchemy` to use the correct engine using the `drivername` argument of `URL.create`:

```py
# example values
engine = create_engine(
    URL.create(
        drivername="redshift+psycopg2",
        username="username",
        password="password",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=5439,
        database="dev",
    )
)
```

Before it was `drivername="postgresql+psycopg2"`, when it should have been `drivername="redshift+psycopg2"`.